# Generate item list from file folders for batch build

Tags: msbuild, batch-processing

I would like to batch build a project for different customers and each customer has its own subfolder in the project.

```
root
  customers
    customer1
    customer2
```

Is there a way to generate a list in msbuild to batch build a project with a `/p:customer=name of customer folder`?
So that inside the project file I could include certain files from `%(customer)`.

Answer (score 0):

First list the directories (1), then get the last part of it (2), then loop over it (3):

```
<Target Name="Batch">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- (1) don't forget to replace rootdir with your dir -->
    <CustomerDirs Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(rootdir, *, SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />

    <!-- (2) -->
    <Customers Include="@(CustomerDirs->'%(FileName)')"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- (3) -->
  <Message Text="customer=%(Customers.Identity)"/>
</Target>
```